# How to configure Nginx/Apache to enable HTTPS with EC2 Instance?

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, https

I have an EC2 instance set up with a load balancer with the following security group rules
[image]

and a load balancer that forwards requests for http and https, with a certificate generated by AWS Certificate Managr.

[image]

I used route 53 to create an A name record that points to my load balancer DNS name, and an elastic ip that I use for my registrar to use.

I can reach my http site fine (e.g. `http://3.143.193.162:3001`) but not for https.

How do I configure apache/nginx to accept `https` with the certificate and load balancer i am using?

Answer (score 0):

When you created your target group what protocol did you tell it to use to connect to the targets? Typically even though your ALB may listen on http and https it will connect to your back end servers using one protocol.

[image: Target group]

Here it is in the ALB wizard

[image: Target group]

Here's where you set up the load balancer to accept http and https

[image: ALB]

Basically we need a bit more info to fully answer your question, but this should give you some things to look at.